# What is the Emperor's Chosen?

Tags: warhammer-40k-chaos-gate

In *Warhammer 40,000: Chaos Gate*, Brother Ectar gave pleasing news that a knight made an unexpected complete and near-instantaneous recovery, rare enough that the Apothecaries deemed him one of the Emperor's Chosen, not needing any further augmentation. What does it mean?

[image: Warhammer 40,000: Chaos Gate - The Emperor's Chosen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means he has recovered at full HP in faster than usual time, no longer able to receive augmentations from critical recoveries, but rewarded the Champion (Passive).

[image: Warhammer 40,000: Chaos Gate - Champion (Passive)]